# Chrome Extension: Read all Bookmarks to the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first extension and would like to log all the bookmarks to the console.
If got this code until know and the error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage') at HTMLButtonElement.

This is the code I've got until now. Can you help me to find the error?
Thanks a lot!!
Martin

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Meine Chrome-Erweiterung",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Beschreibung der Erweiterung",
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Meine Chrome-Erweiterung</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Meine Chrome-Erweiterung</h1>
  <button id="bookmarkButton">Lesezeichen abrufen</button>
  <!-- Weitere Inhalte der Popup-Seite hier... -->
</body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
// Hintergrundskript

// Lesezeichen abrufen
function getBookmarks(callback) {
  chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function (bookmarks) {
    callback(bookmarks);
  });
}

// Listener zum Empfangen der Nachricht vom Popup-Skript
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'getBookmarks') {
    getBookmarks(function (bookmarks) {
      sendResponse({ action: 'sendBookmarks', bookmarks: bookmarks });
    });
  }
  return true; // Wichtig für asynchrone Rückmeldung
});
```

popup.js

```
// Popup-Skript

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var bookmarkButton = document.getElementById('bookmarkButton');
  if (bookmarkButton) {
    bookmarkButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getBookmarks' }, function (response) {
        if (response && response.action === 'sendBookmarks') {
          console.log(response.bookmarks);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```